# Multiple OracleCommands per OracleConnection

Tags: c#

I am opening a connection to a database in which I need to issue multiple deletes before closing the connection.  I have the following code but it looks strange with all the using statements.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is this the correct way to use the using statement with connections/commands?

```
using(OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    string table1Command= "DELETE FROM TABLE1...";
    using(OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(table1Command, oracleConnection))
    {
        oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    string table2Command= "DELETE FROM TABLE2...";
    using(OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(table2Command, oracleConnection))
    {
        oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function:

```
void InvokeCommand (OracleConnection oracleConnection, string tableCommand) 
{
     using(OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(tableCommand, oracleConnection)) 
     { 
         oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Yea.  I see what you mean.  What I was really trying to get at though is that the correct way to use the using statement with connections/commands.  I can see how this wasn't apparent in the question.

Comment: I am not familiar with this specific API. If the command is asynchronous then the usings are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `using` statement correctly.  Both `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand` should be Disposed of when you are finished with them, and the `using` statement is the clearest way of doing this within the bounds of a method.

There are some subtleties regarding how ConnectionPooling is configured, but I think that's beyond the scope of your question.

---

`*` Note that the `OracleConnection` class is **not** Thread-Safe, meaning that if you try to re-use `OracleConnection` instances then you have to make sure multiple threads don't use the same instance at the same time.